# Sound does not consistently work properly

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, sound, sound-blaster

Since installing Ubuntu (both 18.04 and 20.04), I have had issues with the sound not working properly consistently. About 9 out of 10 times I boot up my PC, the sound will work but it will be very quiet, have no bass and is very muffled; in order to hear anything I have to enable 'Over Amplification' and max everything all the way out just to be able to hear terrible quality sound. The other 1 in 10 times the sound will work perfectly with absolutely no issues. I have also noticed that occasionally the sound will work properly after I suspend my computer for a while and wake it up again.

My motherboard (GA-Z270x GA8) has a Sound Blaster ZxRi sound card built in. I would like to start debugging this issue but wouldn't know where to start.